# Display name on the basis of user sign in on Tableau

Tags: sql-server, tableau-api

I want to display name on Tableau dashboard on the basis of sign in. 
Is it possible if Sam logins then it should say Hello Sam, or if Mark logins with his id, it should say
Hi Mark.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try creating a calculated field-

```
'Hello ' + USERNAME()
```

[Tableau User Functions](https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/functions_functions_user.htm)